# Should BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray be on a background thread?

Tags: android, performance

Is it wise to call [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte%5B%5D%2C%20int%2C%20int)) on the UI thread or should you always do it in a background task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html

The one of the advantage using background thread (Asynch Task etc) for bitmap operation,we can get rid from ANR(A pplication N ot R esponding. ) when downloading bitmap from URL perhaps go anything wrong.preffering you to follow painless threading http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html for app construction while working with long running task.

Comment: The **one of the advantage using UI thread for bitmap operation**,we can get rid from ANR(A pplication N ot R esponding. )...http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html. It should be thread not ui thread

Answer (score 3):

For a large image, absolutely.  You can get away with it on the main thread for a small image or two, but it can definitely cause performance issues if you use it on too big an image or too many small ones.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is YES, in all the cases. You never know the device on which the code will run. And on low end devices even decoding a small image can cause an ugly user experience - blocking the main thread. The decode methods are pretty optimised - they are written and run Native... but this doesn't save you on low end devices, or big images, or in the case you have a list with many items.

Comment: so you are always inflating the layouts in the background thread? never call setContentView(int layoutId)  in the main UI thread?

Comment: @pskink I think we are talking about decoding images, and where this process should occur - on the UI, or on a background thread. I can't get the reference to the layouts inflation and the setContentView. A part of that, I'm pretty sure you can not execute the setContentView on a non-UI thread - it should throw an exception.

Comment: but you know that calling setContentView in 99% cases calls one on BitmapFactory methods?  so in your opinion you should always build the view hierarchy in the background thread and set it in the ui thread?  i don't think its a common scenario

Comment: @pskink My opinion, is that probably the _most common use_ of this, is to load and show an image in your UI - not composing custom views or layouts, and loading _resources_ for them. This is the point of view I’m taking this question and answering it. May be this is causing the misunderstanding. But, if I’m right and you are loading image previews… YES do it in the background, even if they are small images.<br/>Of course - this is only my opinion and approach :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to process it on one Thread if you have lots of large image.
eg: listview will be displaying lots of images for each item,
just only one image I think you haven't to, because of a thread needs cpu and RAM

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you should always decode resources on a separate thread and keep them in memory for future uses. I had lots of ANR's (Application Not Responding) for the simple fact of calling ContextCompat.getDrawable(resId) inside a RecyclerView item. You should:

1. Decode resource in background thread and save in memory.
2. Post the result to the Adapter
3. Then use it.

The most interesting part is that, those resources managed to raise an ANR even though they were being called from the Disk, not from the network! This happens a lot in low end devices. And developers should always keep the code running smoothly on every device, otherwise Google Play will penalize your app for exceding 0.43% max threshold of ANR's.